# How to write complex mySQL select in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to write the following mySQL query into a PHP format that I need to execute for multiple schemas. This query generates a data dictionary.

```
select  t.table_schema as schema_name, 
    t.table_name,   
        (case when t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' then 'table' 
         when t.table_type = 'VIEW' then 'view'  
         else t.table_type end) as table_type, 
    c.column_name,  
    c.column_type,
    c.column_default,   
        (case when c.column_key = ' ' then '-'
         when c.column_key = 'MUL' then 'FK'
         else 'PK' end) as column_key,
    c.is_nullable,    
    c.column_comment    
from information_schema.tables as t 
inner join information_schema.columns as c on t.table_name = c.table_name and t.table_schema = c.table_schema 
where t.table_type in('base table', 'view') and t.table_schema = 'testdb'
order by t.table_schema, t.table_name, c.ordinal_position
```

I tried using the following syntax in PHP:

```
$sql = "select t.table_schema as schema_name, 
            t.table_name,   
                (case when t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' then 'table' 
                 when t.table_type = 'VIEW' then 'view'  
                 else t.table_type end) as table_type, 
            c.column_name,  
            c.column_type,
            c.column_default,   
                (case when c.column_key = ' ' then '-'
                 when c.column_key = 'MUL' then 'FK'
                 else 'PK' end) as column_key,
            c.is_nullable,    
            c.column_comment    
            from information_schema.tables as t 
            inner join information_schema.columns as c on t.table_name = c.table_name and t.table_schema = c.table_schema 
            where t.table_type in('base table', 'view') and t.table_schema = 'testdb'
            order by t.table_schema, t.table_name, c.ordinal_position";
```

But then when I execute this I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: t.table_schema in C:\laragon\www\createDict.php on line 32
schema_name:
```

I used this to create the output (for now just for the first column):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            echo "schema_name: " . $row["t.table_schema"]."<br>";
        }
```

I would really apprecitate it if someone could help me with this. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you have:

```
select t.table_schema as schema_name
```

So, once you get the result back in PHP, the array with data will call this "schema_name". You should use:

```
echo "schema_name: " . $row["schema_name"]."<br>";
```

Side note: result arrays in PHP do not include the table name in the data, so where you're selecting `c.column_type`, you will need to get the value using `$row['column_type']` -- without the `c.` part.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was really helpful. I managed to create the whole output table now. One more question, if you don't mind. How can I pass t.table_schema = 'testdb' as a parameter instead of 'testdb'?

Comment: If you're using PDO, use a [parameterized query](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/5828/pdo/2685/preventing-sql-injection-with-parameterized-queries#t=20170609164318773973); if you're using mysqli, use a [prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/2784/php-mysqli/11958/prepared-statements-in-mysqli#t=201706091643399614308).

Comment: Got it all set! Thank you very much!